# Unity3d drag an object with finger problems

Tags: drag-and-drop, unity-game-engine

I am making a script to drag an object on Y axis. It is almost done, but I have one problem. When I click the object, center of object moves to the mouse position, and then I drag it like that so the center is always on mouse position. How can I make when I hold for example bottom of the sprite, center of sprite stays where it is and it doesn't move to the mouse position?
Here is my script:

```
    public Vector3 screenPoint;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void OnMouseDown(){
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint (gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
    }

    void OnMouseDrag(){
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint), offset;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, curPosition.y, transform.position.z);
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `curScreenPoint` is still in pixel coordinates. The one you did in `OnMouseDown` was correct. So you should also convert the pixel coordinates in `OnMouseDrag` to screen space:

Change this line:

```
Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, 
                                     Input.mousePosition.y, 
                                     screenPoint.z);
```

To this:

```
Vector3 curScreenPoint = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (
                                                         Input.mousePosition.x, 
                                                         Input.mousePosition.y, 
                                                         screenPoint.z)
                                                        );
```

Also I don't quite understand what you're doing in this line:

```
Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint), offset;
```

But it should be like this since you only want to move the Y:

```
Vector3 curPosition = new Vector3(curScreenPoint.x, 
                                  curScreenPoint.y + offset.y, 
                                  curScreenPoint.z);
```

Comment: One more question. How can I limit movement and set max top spot and max bot spot so the object can move only from one to other?

Comment: You can use [Mathf.Clamp](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) to restrict max and min coordinates.